# Dash Multi-Page Dropdown

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

```
import dash
from dash import Dash, html, dcc

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Multi-page app with Dash Pages'),
    html.Div([
        html.Div(
            dcc.Link(f"{page['name']}", href=page["relative_path"])
        ) for page in dash.page_registry.values()
    ]),
    dash.page_container
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want dcc.dropdown instead of dcc.link but the working should same like the pages  name should be the option and when i select one of them, that page will load with the path example: in dropdown fruits is selected then fruits dash will load and url be like: http://127.0.0.1:8050/fruits

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, Dash

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True)

# Convert page registry values to a list
pages_list = list(dash.page_registry.values())

# Create a dropdown for page selection
page_dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="page-dropdown",
    options=[{"label": page["name"], "value": page["relative_path"]} for page in pages_list],
    value=pages_list[0]["relative_path"]  # Set initial value to the first page
)
# Layout of the main app
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H3("Multi-Page App"),
    page_dropdown,  # Add the dropdown to the layout
    dash.page_container
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tried the above code but its not working when I am changing URL path then its loading but when i select anything from the dropdown option nothing happen.

Comment: did you ever manage to resolve this as above rather than explicitly listing?

Answer (score 0):

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.H1('My Demo App'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='page-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Page 1', 'value': '/page-1'},
            {'label': 'Page 2', 'value': '/page-2'},
        ],
        value='/page-1'
    ),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])

index_page = html.Div([
    html.H2('This is the index page'),
])

page_1_layout = html.Div([
    html.H2('Page 1'),
])

page_2_layout = html.Div([
    html.H2('Page 2'),
])

@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')])
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/page-1':
        return page_1_layout
    elif pathname == '/page-2':
        return page_2_layout
    else:
        return index_page

@app.callback(Output('url', 'pathname'),
              [Input('page-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_url(value):
    return value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```